# ValueError: shapes (831,18) and (1629,2) not aligned: 18 (dim 1) != 1629 (dim 0)

Tags: python, dataframe, machine-learning, scikit-learn

So I've been trying to classify popularity of a song based on its lyrics and other parameters like tempo etc. Now here's the snippet of code I'm trying to run via tkinter.

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn_pandas import DataFrameMapper
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfTransformer, TfidfVectorizer,CountVectorizer

df = pd.read_csv(r'Dataset(Advanced)(processed lyrics).csv') 

df['Lyrics'] = df['Lyrics'].astype(str)   

mapper = DataFrameMapper([('Lyrics', CountVectorizer()),
  ('Tempo', None),
  ('Energy', None),
   ('Loudness', None),
  ('Danceability', None),
  ('Speechiness', None),
  ('Acousticness', None),
 ('Artist Hit', None)
 ])

features = mapper.fit_transform(df[['Lyrics', 'Tempo', 'Energy', 'Loudness', 'Danceability', 'Speechiness'
                                , 'Acousticness', 'Artist Hit']])
y = df['Hit']

from sklearn.naive_bayes import MultinomialNB
model = MultinomialNB()

model.fit(features, y)
```

Now, this is the function I call when I click on a button. Here I take all the values such as lyrics, tempo etc for a song and convert it to dataframe attribute to fit it in DataFrameMapper. While all of this looks good,

```
def predict():
user_Lyrics = lyricsTextBox2.get(1.0, "end-1c")
user_Lyrics = user_Lyrics.values.astype(str)
print(user_Lyrics.head())
print(type(user_Lyrics))

# Everything in lowercase
user_Lyrics = user_Lyrics.apply(lambda x: " ".join(x.lower() for x in str(x).split()))

# Removing punctuation that does not add meaning to the song
user_Lyrics = user_Lyrics.str.replace('[^\w\s]', '')

# Removing of stop words
from nltk.corpus import stopwords

stop = stopwords.words('english')
user_Lyrics = user_Lyrics.apply(lambda x: " ".join(x for x in str(x).split() if x not in stop))

# Correction of Spelling mistakes
from textblob import TextBlob
user_Lyrics = user_Lyrics.apply(lambda x: str(TextBlob(x).correct()))

# Lemmatization is basically converting a word into its root word. It is preferred over Stemming.
from textblob import Word
user_Lyrics = user_Lyrics.apply(lambda x: " ".join([Word(word).lemmatize() for word in x.split()]))



df['AP'] = float(ArtistPopularityEntry.get())
df['SE'] = float(EnergyEntry.get())
df['SL'] = float(LoudnessEntry.get())
df['SA'] = float(AcousticnessEntry.get())
df['ST'] = float(TempoEntry.get())
df['SD'] = float(DanceabilityEntry.get())
df['SS'] = float(SpeechinessEntry.get())

mapper2 = DataFrameMapper([
    ('Lyrics_User', CountVectorizer()),
    ('ST', None),
    ('SE', None),
    ('SL', None),
    ('SD', None),
    ('SS', None),
    ('SA', None),
    ('AP', None)
])
features2 = mapper2.fit_transform(df[['Lyrics_User', 'ST', 'SE', 'SL', 'SD', 'SS', 'SA', 'AP']])

print(type(features2))
print(len(features2))
print(features2.shape)

print(type(features))
print(len(features))
print(features.shape)

user_prediction = model.predict(features2)
print(user_prediction)
if (user_prediction[0] == 1):
    resultLabel2.config(text='Song is Hit')
else:
    resultLabel2.config(text='Song is not Hit')
```

Output:

```
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
831
(831, 18)
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
831
(831, 1629)

Error: 

Exception in Tkinter callback Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:\Users\moksh\Anaconda3\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1702, in
    __call__
        return self.func(*args)   File "<ipython-input-4-f6ddab248363>", 
line 69, in predict
        user_prediction = model.predict(features2)   File 
"C:\Users\moksh\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\naive_bayes.py", line 
66, in predict
        jll = self._joint_log_likelihood(X)   File 
"C:\Users\moksh\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\naive_bayes.py", line 
725, in _joint_log_likelihood
        return (safe_sparse_dot(X, self.feature_log_prob_.T) +   File 
"C:\Users\moksh\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\extmath.py", 
line 140, in safe_sparse_dot
        return np.dot(a, b) ValueError: shapes (831,18) and (1629,2) not 
aligned: 18 (dim 1) != 1629 (dim 0)
```

**EDIT**

```
 df['AP'] = float(ArtistPopularityEntry.get())
 df['SE'] = float(EnergyEntry.get())
 df['ST'] = float(TempoEntry.get())


 features2 = mapper.transform(df[['Lyrics_User', 'ST', 'SE', 'AP']])
```

This gives another error:

> Exception in Tkinter callback Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File
>   "C:\Users\moksh\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py",
>   line 3063, in get_loc
>       return self._engine.get_loc(key)   File "pandas_libs\index.pyx", line 140, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc   File
>   "pandas_libs\index.pyx", line 162, in
>   pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc   File
>   "pandas_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1492, in
>   pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item   File
>   "pandas_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1500, in
>   pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item KeyError: 'Lyrics'
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:\Users\moksh\Anaconda3\lib\tkinter__init__.py", line 1702, in
>   **call**
>       return self.func(*args)   File "", line 53, in predict
>       features2 = mapper.transform(df[['Lyrics_User', 'ST', 'SE', 'AP']])   File
>   "C:\Users\moksh\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn_pandas\dataframe_mapper.py",
>   line 289, in transform
>       Xt = self._get_col_subset(X, columns, input_df)   File "C:\Users\moksh\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn_pandas\dataframe_mapper.py",
>   line 182, in _get_col_subset
>       t = X[cols[0]]   File "C:\Users\moksh\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py",
>   line 2685, in **getitem**
>       return self._getitem_column(key)   File "C:\Users\moksh\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py",
>   line 2692, in _getitem_column
>       return self._get_item_cache(key)   File "C:\Users\moksh\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py",
>   line 2486, in _get_item_cache
>       values = self._data.get(item)   File "C:\Users\moksh\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals.py",
>   line 4115, in get
>       loc = self.items.get_loc(item)   File "C:\Users\moksh\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py",
>   line 3065, in get_loc
>       return self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))   File "pandas_libs\index.pyx", line 140, in
>   pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc   File
>   "pandas_libs\index.pyx", line 162, in
>   pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc   File
>   "pandas_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1492, in
>   pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item   File
>   "pandas_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1500, in
>   pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item KeyError: 'Lyrics'

Comment: Obviously, you are trying to multiply two matrices that don't have the proper dimensions. What have you done check where the bad dimensions come from?

Comment: Pretty obvious, yes. But I just can't manage to find the source of bad dimensions.

Comment: Have you tried outputting shapes? For instance what you have in your original model, and what you are using in your new data.

Comment: I edited the question to include the output to the print statements beneath 'features2'. I can't seem to be able to rectify the problem. Obviously, there's a dimension mismatch. Dummy me. Is there a viable solution to this?

Comment: This looks like it has nothing to do with tkinter.

Comment: There is a mismatch somewhere. You have 18 features (18 columns) in your original data, not 8. First issue. Second issue, your second data set has 1629 features. That's not correct either.

Answer (score 0):

You are fitting two different `CountVectorizer` objects (1 for training and other for prediction), which learns two different vocabulary sets.

During training, since the data is large and consists of multiple samples, it produces a vocabulary of 1629 words. But during prediction, since you are only using it to predict a single sample, the vocabulary is 18.

This is the source of error.

Now tell me why are you using the same `model` object, instead of a new one while predicting? That's because the new `model` will not have learnt anything. In the same way, the original `CountVectorizer` object inside the `mapper` has learnt something about your data which needs to be used while predicting.

Instead of declaring a new object `mapper2` and call `fit_transform()` (which will learn about the data passed it to from scratch), you need to use the old `mapper` (which is already fitted), and call transform() on it.

Instead of :

```
mapper2 = DataFrameMapper([
    ('Lyrics_User', CountVectorizer()),
    ('ST', None),
    ('SE', None),
    ('SL', None),
    ('SD', None),
    ('SS', None),
    ('SA', None),
    ('AP', None)
])
features2 = mapper2.fit_transform(df[['Lyrics_User', 'ST', 'SE', 'SL', 'SD', 'SS', 'SA', 'AP']])
```

Do this:

```
features2 = mapper.transform(df[['Lyrics', 'ST', 'SE', 'SL', 'SD', 'SS', 'SA', 'AP']])
```

Comment: Thanks you for such a detailed response, I really appreciate that! I tried doing this, it gave me another error. (Edit)

Comment: @MokshVerma You need to have same column names as in your original mapper. I'm sorry I missed that. You need to change `Lyrics_User` to `Lyrics`